# Integral of the Product of a Function and Its Derivative

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, circles, gre-exam

Problem: Let $f$ be a function such that the graph of $f$ is a semicircle $S$ with end points $(a,0)$ and $(b,0)$, where $a < b$. The improper integral $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) f'(x) dx$ is

(A) necessarily zero

(B) possibly zero but not necessarily zero

(C) necessarily nonexistent

(D) possibly nonexistent but not necessarily

(E) none of the above

This is a practice problem for timed test, so I am looking for the quickest solution.  Here is what I came up with. Right from the beginning it is rather hand-wavy. It suffices to transform the circle into the unit circle centered at $(0,0)$. In that case, the integral becomes $\int_{-1}^{1} f(x) f'(x) dx$, where $f(-1)=f(1)$. Since $\frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dx}f(x)^2 = f(x) f'(x)$, the integral becomes

$$\frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^{1} dx f(x)^2 dx = \frac{1}{2} [f(1)^2 - f(-1)^2] = 0,$$

which means that (A) is the correct choice.

My question is, how do I make this idea of transforming the circle more rigorous? I have never actually done anything like this before, but I could see geometrically that it would work. How do I make this step more rigorous?

Answer (score 3):

With the substitution $u = f(x)$, $du = f'(x) \, dx$, we get $$\int f(x) f'(x) \, dx = \int u \, du = \frac{u^2}{2} + C = \frac{(f(x))^2}{2} + C.$$  Since $f(a) = f(b) = 0$, the result immediately follows.

---

It is also worth noting that we can explicitly compute $$f(x) = \pm \sqrt{((b-a)/2)^2 - (x-(a+b)/2)^2}, \\ f'(x) = \frac{-(x-(a+b)/2)}{f(x)},$$ so that $$f(x) f'(x) = \frac{a+b}{2} - x, \quad a < x < b.$$  But it is clear from the previous calculation that $f$ need not be explicitly stated:  as long as $f(a)^2 = f(b)^2$ and certain regularity conditions hold (what are these?), then the integral will be zero.

Comment: Ah! For some strange reason I was thinking that $f(a)=f(b)=0$ isn't as obvious $f(-1)=f(1)=0$. But we are given that $(a,0)$ and $(b,0)$ are endpoints---so $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ better be zero! Thanks for pointing out boneheaded I am! :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to transform the circle, just apply your method directly to the original problem. Namely,

$$ \int_a^b f(x) f'(x) \, dx = \left[ \frac{f^2(x)}{2} \right]_{x = a}^{x = b} = \frac{f(b)^2 - f(a)^2}{2} = 0 $$

because $f(a) = f(b) = 0$ (the graph of $f$ passes through $(a,0)$ and $(b,0)$).